# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when setting synthesized (retained) property to nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, exc-bad-access, null

I get a bad access (objc_msgsend) when calling this line of code:

```
self.currentGameTeam = nil;
```

Where "currentGameTeam" is defined in the interface for a class called "MCState" as:

```
MNAvailableTeamContext *currentGameTeam;
```

And I synthesize a property for it:

```
@property (retain) MNAvailableTeamContext *currentGameTeam;
```

After setting NSZombieEnabled the console shows:

```
*** -[MNAvailableTeamContext release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5b3eba0
```

And the debugger trace shows that it comes from within the synthesized setter code:

```
#3  0x0001fa96 in -[MCState setCurrentGameTeam:] at MCState.m:44
```

I've looked at several other questions and threads and I can't find an answer that applies to my case. I don't understand why there would be a bad access if I've synthesized the property and I'm setting it to nil. What is especially odd is that there are at least 3 other properties in MCState which are defined and used in the exact same way as currentGameTeam, with the only difference being that they are different types:

```
MNUserContext *storedUser;
MNActiveGameContext *storedGame;
MNAvailableUserContext *storedGameUser;
MNAvailableTeamContext *storedGameTeam;
```

and

```
@property (retain) MNUserContext *currentUser;
@property (retain) MNActiveGameContext *currentGame;
@property (retain) MNAvailableUserContext *currentGameUser;
@property (retain) MNAvailableTeamContext *currentGameTeam;
```

and

```
@synthesize currentUser;
@synthesize currentGame;
@synthesize currentGameUser;
@synthesize currentGameTeam;
```

finally

```
self.currentUser = userContext;
self.currentGame = nil;
self.currentGameUser = nil;
self.currentGameTeam = nil; // Error occurs here
```

The rest of these all act normally - only currentGameTeam gives me trouble. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is `self.currentGameTeam = nil;` located exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhere, `currentGameTeam` is being released before you attempt to set it to nil.  Setting a retained property to nil implies a release to be called.  Calling release on an object that has already been released will result in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  This is confirmed with your running with NSZombies enabled.

You can run with Instruments with the Zombies tool - it will give you more detail about all of the retains, releases and autoreleases leading up to the zombie call.

Comment: I know about the Zombies instrument, but its always disabled in the menu. What do I have to do to be able to use it?

Comment: It's a bit tricky... it can only be run with the simulator, not the device... and you have to actually setup with the Allocation instrument, then configure the Allocation instrument for Zombies (while not profiling), then attach / start the process.

Comment: Why does "self.currentGameTeam = nil" cause a message to be sent to a deallocated instance? Surely the whole point of using a setter is that it automatically takes care of the release/retain cycle? I ask this, because I seem to be having the same problem but I don't understand why! :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ivar named currentGameTeam ?

Comment: Excuse me for not understanding, but what do you mean, do I "have" it?

Comment: I mean is there an instance variable named currentGameTeam declared in your interface ?

Comment: Yes - I thought I stated that in my question at the top. It is declared as an instance variable of the class MCState. The code that produces the error is also within MCState. It is a large class so I did not want to explicitly print all the code on here.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Then you are probably creating an autoreleased MNAvailableTeamContext and assign it to currentGameTeam directly and not using property.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. I only assign something to currentGameTeam in a few places and every time I use the synthesized setter via "self." etc. Even so, why would it throw a bad access when setting the property to 'nil'? That is what most puzzles me.

Comment: when you are setting the retain property to nil the release message is sent to that object.

Comment: A little trick: set the breakpoint in the MNAvailableTeamContext dealloc method and you'll be able to see all deallocations, that were performed.

Comment: That is a good common sense trick. I tried it out and although it didn't completely solve the problem, it did cause me to find another bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some bugs like this an usually tracked them down to a typo someplace where I meant to type `currentGameUser` but have typed `currentGameTeam` so I end up double-releasing one of the objects and not releasing another. I would try doing a `Build and Analyze` to and if that doesn't find anything try `Run with Performance Tool > Leaks`.

I say this since your code looks fine except you declare `stored*` and then declare and synthesize properties for `current*`, which looks like an inconsistency so there may be other places where this kinds of close-but-different typos may have occurred.

Comment: Right sorry for the inconsistency. I have another set of similar values prefixed with 'stored', and I pasted the wrong section into the question. It should have been 'current'. Also, I checked for what you said just in case, but I don't think its the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Last time set to nil should already set that to nil.

So the next time set to nil should not harmful. Not sure why crash.